# npm stucked on renaming non-existing folder (Windows)

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a problem with npm update command like:

```
npm update -g
```

It always terminates with error

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.node-gyp.DELETE\node_modules\@npmcli
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename
```

The problem is the folder given in the error msg does not exist, so it's obvious, it can't be renamed. Tried to create one but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

So finally I had to reinstall node.js.